# How Java overloading works?

Tags: java, overloading

Suppose I have this java program. Why does it print "foo"?

```
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}

class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Foo object = new Bar();
        
        printSomething(object);
    }

    public static void printSomething(Foo f) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public static void printSomething(Bar b) {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
}
```

I know about overriding and late binding but I'm not used to overloading? Is the type of *object* checked at runtime so that the most specific method gets called? And what about primitive values?

Comment: Have you run it?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca OP's question is theoretical. I think they misphrased it, though, I believe what they meant was "Why does it print `foo`"?

Comment: Well it was a retoric question. Btw I run it and get an unexpected "foo". So it solves also my doubt on primitive types..

Comment: Why would it be unexpected? Read my answer, please.

Comment: I read it, thank you. My main concern was about overloading a method with a hierarchy of types.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading is basically using the same method name with different arguments. Your example will print "foo", because you're passing it an object of type `Foo`, and Java calls the first overload because it expects such an object. Let's do a simpler example (with primitives, since you asked):

```java
class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        addPrint(15, 20);
        addPrint("Hello, ", "world!");
    }

    // This method will add two ints and print the result.
    public static void addPrint(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }

    // This is the same as the first method, but it will add Strings instead.
    // Please note - do not use a method for this. This is done purely for the example.
    public static void addPrint(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a + b); // this will add the two strings together just like ints
    }
}
```

What this essentially does is first call `addPrint(int, int)` with the arguments `15` and `20` - which are ints, so Java will know what to call, since the first overload expects two ints. The second time, it will look for an overload with two Strings (or classes that inherit from `String`), and if it finds something - it will call it. Otherwise, it'll just cry during compile-time that it can't find a proper overload.

You can also refer to [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/) for more info.

Tip - overloading works pretty much the same in other languages, e.g. C#.